# Change remote server's hostname with ansible

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ansible, hostname

I want to change my remote server's hostname so I used the [hostname module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/hostname_module.html):

```
- hostname: name="{{my_hostname}}"
```

But that also changed the `ansible_host` to that value, and so messed up remaining tasks.

When I did it manually:

```
- shell: hostnamectl set-hostname {{my_hostname}}
```

Then the remote server's hostname was changed, AND the `ansible_host` global var wasn't changed, and all remaining plays completed successfully.

*Am I using the `hostname` module correctly? I have a feeling it doesn't do what I think.*

(I also noticed lots of bug reports in the repo, but I'm not sure if they're related to what I'm doing as I'm not using cloud-init).

Comment: Are you using some kind of dynamic inventory? And where are you using `ansible_host`?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I thought `ansible_host` comes from the hosts inventory file, as one of those built-in variables? Regardless, is the code above supposed to work, or did I use the wrong module?

Comment: `ansible_host` comes from the host's own hostname. It can be wrong, which is presumably why you are changing it! The inventory hostname is stored in `inventory_hostname`. Most of the time, `inventory_hostname` is what you want to use in your own playbooks to refer to your hosts.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks for the clarification! Does the `hostname` module do what I think it does - change the hostname of the remote server?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it is documented to do.

Comment: @Ionix - it's a fine distinction, but `hostname:` module changes the *target* host's hostname.  It doesn't have to be remote, it can be used on the local system (ansible controller) as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should know the difference between `inventory_hostname` (how you call it) and `ansible_host` (how you reach it). You could use the ip-address as `ansible_host` in your inventory entry:

```
   my_hostname ansible_host=192.168.12.34
```

Then use the hostname module to change the hostname of the machine to "{{ inventory_hostname }}".